# How to error free"ColumnName Already Belongs to datatable "?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, wpfdatagrid

Hai  am write the code below in c#,it always error as column already belongs to this datatable.i dnt knw how to error free.the below code is am used.

```
private void Send_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 System.Data.DataRowView selectedFile = (System.Data.DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItem;
 string studid = Convert.ToString(selectedFile.Row.ItemArray[3]);
 DataRow row = tabl.NewRow();
 tabl.Columns.Add("StudyUID", typeof(string));
 tabl.Columns.Add("Patient ID");
 tabl.Columns.Add("Patient Name");
 row["StudyUID"] = selectedFile.Row.ItemArray[3];
 row["Patient ID"] = selectedFile.Row.ItemArray[1];
 row["Patient Name"] = selectedFile.Row.ItemArray[2];
 sendstudy(this.SUID, row);
}
```

I need how to avoid the error "column already belongs to this datatable"

thanks in Advance

Comment: Help me please,am stuck here

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? The error states that the datatable already has the columns set up. Did you set the names up somewhere else? Can you remove all the tabl.columns.add code and will it work then. Also, not sure why your writing it like this. You have a datatable, you create a row,but you never add the row to the datatable.

Comment: @sjramsay :am already added that in dataGrid,and also for each time send click,it shows error as am quoated above

Comment: Can you show the code where you define your tabl DataTable? What is happening in you keep adding the columns every time you add a new row and you don't need to do that. Once you have the table and the columns defined, outside your send_click event, then you can addyour rows. If you added your columns in the datagrid, then you don't need the columns here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add columns for every new row - once the columns are defined, they'll be included in every new row.  Just delete these lines:

```
 tabl.Columns.Add("StudyUID", typeof(string));
 tabl.Columns.Add("Patient ID");
 tabl.Columns.Add("Patient Name");
```

Comment: :If am delete this ,one time only i can click send button,if am again click means it shows "Column name already belongs to dataTable "

Comment: Am really fedup here,plz help me sir

Comment: Somewhere in your code you create the DataTable tabl.  Move the 3 lines there so they are only executed once.

Answer (score 0):

this error means you don't declare a  new row to data table but want to add that row to data table.
every time,befor adding a row to data table  insert code:  DataRow row = tabl.NewRow();
and one more thing, you must declare your table column just one time (befor adding any row to it).